# Search content within attachment file in SharePoint Office 365

Tags: fast-search, sharepoint-search

Is there any way to search the content of attachment file of a SharePoint **List**. Specifically I have to find content in an attachment.

Comment: Do you mean that you ONLY want to search attachments?

Comment: yes, i want results which is having search text in attachments only.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wont be possible. There are specific reasons why list and libraries exists in SharePoint. SharePoint only crawl the Attachment Name and index it. It never crawls the Attachment content. For this purpose we have document libraries.

But there is a workaround to your problem, described here. [Search and index pdf files as attachment in a List Item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114213/search-and-index-pdf-files-as-attachment-in-a-list-item)

Answer (score 1):

List item attachments should be indexed if I'm not mistaken. Have you tried and it fails, ans what type of file is the attachment?

Comment: Office documents,  it's giving results but I have to restrict it to search only in attachments not other list metadata like title, description,

Comment: If data and search is scoped to one particular site/site collection, you can map the crawled properties for your metadata to a managed property which is neither queryable nor searchable, then re-index the list items, in the search schema scoped at that level. This will ensure the metadata is nulled from the full-text index. If it's data across multiple site collections, you probably don't want to null the columns, unless they have a very unique column names. Mapping the cp's like this will also cripple search for that list, when using the list searchbox.